# How to solve flickering of far objects which color is attributed through VertexAttribute.ColorUnpacked()

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl

I know that there is something called mip-mapping where you can reduce the quality of textures over distance from camera wtih  `Gdx.gl.glGenerateMipmap();`

However, I can't do that because I am using color attribute.
Is there any way for me to achieve mip mapping for the colors?

im using libgdx, and i can implements glsl shaders if needed

Thanks in advance

Edit, I want to change the flickering in the red circle. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I can't do that because I am using color attribute.

If by that, you mean that the colors are produced by per-vertex attributes, and the whole thing is a dense mesh that's a square... then there's not much you can do.

You can attempt to employ multisampling, but that can only do so much.